# Group by values in one column

Tags: mysql

I have a table with this data in it:

```
ID     Name     Color
1      Kyle     Blue
1      Susan    Orange
1      Steven   Orange
2      Susan    Blue
```

I want to use a query like this:

```
Select * from table group by ID, Top1(Name), Top1(Color)
```

So I get these results:

```
ID     Name     Color
1      Kyle     Blue
2      Susan    Blue
```

I don't care if it's Kyle Blue, or Steven Orange as long as the color matches the name.

Comment: Please format your question properly.

Answer (score 1):

Eg

```
SELECT x.*
  FROM my_table x
  JOIN (SELECT id, MIN(name) min_name FROM my_table GROUP BY id) y
    ON y.id = x.id
   AND y.min_name = x.name;
```

Answer (score -1):

select *
from (
   select *,
          row_number() over (partition by Name order by Name) as row_number
   from table
   ) as rows
where row_number = 1

Comment: I"m sorry, I meant MSSQL